# How to implement generic interface whose generic template extending another interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Consider the following scenarios:

```
public interface WinningBatches<X> {
    Collection<X> getBatches();
}

public interface SubBatches<Y, Z extends WinningBatches<Y>> {
    Collection<Z> getGoals(Collection<Y> var);

    void submitTask(Z var);
}
```

I want to implement the interface SubBatches?

I proceeded as follows:

```
public class TotalBatches implements SubBatches<String, String extends WinningBatches<(What to write here?)>> {
    // override the methods of SubBatches.
}
```

I am not able to get how to implement the SubBatches...

Comment: Instead of `String extends WinningBatches<(What to write here?)>`, you can use `WinningBatches<String>` or a type that extends/implements `WinningBatches<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can replace `String extends WinningBatches<(What to write here?)>` by  `WinningBatches<String>`

   ```
   interface TotalBatches extends SubBatches<String, WinningBatches<String>> {
       // override the methods of SubBatches.
   }
   ```
2. Or implement the `WinningBatches` and use it

   ```
   class StringWinningBatches implements WinningBatches<String> {
       @Override
       public Collection<String> getBatches() {
           return null;
       }
   }

   interface TotalBatches extends SubBatches<String, StringWinningBatches> {
       // override the methods of SubBatches.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of `Z` in the extension of `SubBatches<Y, Z extends WinningBatches<Y>>`, or leave it as a generic in `TotalBatches`.

Also, type specification such as `<T extends U>` must be declared by the new interface, not the interface being extended.

Here are 3 examples that should solve your problem:

```
// 1. Without specifying Z
public interface TotalBatches<Z extends WinningBatches<String>> extends SubBatches<String, Z> { }

// 2. Specifying Z   
public interface TotalBatches extends SubBatches<String, WinningBatches<String>> { }

// 3. Using custom extension of WinningBatches   
public interface StringWinningBatches extends WinningBatches<String> { }
public interface TotalBatches extends SubBatches<String, StringWinningBatches> { }
```